# JSON - Aggregating and grouping nested object values

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, object, nested

I'm having a heck of a time flatting/mapping this bit of json. I've setup a fiddle so you can see an example of the structure and my intended output. Essentially I need to tally up each touchpoint's action count but what keeps throwing me off is once I'm looping through the sessions, I cant seem to reference the parent "web" touchpoint to increment the actions.

Here is the fiddle with the json and html: http://jsfiddle.net/Michael_Ellan/Zjbdn/2/

Here is the raw json:

```
{
"stages": {
    "proposition": "15%Off",
    "lifeCycleStages": [
        {
            "lifeCycleStage": "viewing",
            "touchpoints": [
                {
                    "touchpoint": "web",
                    "sessions": [
                        {
                            "actionCount": "2"
                        },
                        {
                            "actionCount": "0"
                        },
                        {
                            "actionCount": "0"
                        },
                        {
                            "actionCount": "3"
                        }
                    ]
                },
                {
                    "touchpoint": "mobile",
                    "sessions": [
                        {
                            "actionCount": "2"
                        },
                        {
                            "actionCount": "0"
                        },
                        {
                            "actionCount": "1"
                        }
                    ]
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            "lifeCycleStage": "buying",
            "touchpoints": [
                {
                    "touchpoint": "web",
                    "sessions": [
                        {
                            "actionCount": "2"
                        },
                        {
                            "actionCount": "0"
                        },
                        {
                            "actionCount": "0"
                        }
                    ]
                },
                {
                    "touchpoint": "mobile",
                    "sessions": [
                        {
                            "actionCount": "4"
                        },
                        {
                            "actionCount": "0"
                        },
                        {
                            "actionCount": "1"
                        }
                    ]
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
}
}
```

Any feedback would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: what is the desired o/p

Comment: The table that I'd like to output can be seen in the fiddle but I've also pasted it below, thanks!

<table>
    <thead>
        <th>
            <tr>
                <th scope="col">Touchpoint</th>
                <th scope="col">viewing</th>
                <th scope="col">buying</th>
            </tr>
        </th>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td>Web</td>
            <td>Actions: 5</td>
            <td>Actions: 2</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Mobile</td>
            <td>Actions: 3</td>
            <td>Actions: 5</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>